# Como alterar a resolução de uma webCam em c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Gostaria de saber como alterar a resolução do dispositivo, a webCam salva até 15mpx porém não consigo alterar a resolução dela no meu programa, ela fica salvando as imagens no tamanho **640x480**. (já tentei alterar pelo software dela, porém as alterações só tem efeito no proprio app dela).

Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public DirectX.Capture.Filter Camera;
        public DirectX.Capture.Capture CaptureInfo;
        public DirectX.Capture.Filters CamContainer;
        public string caminhoImagemSalva = null;
        public Image CapturaImagem;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            CamContainer = new DirectX.Capture.Filters();
            try
            {
                int no_of_cam = CamContainer.VideoInputDevices.Count;
#pragma warning disable CS0162 // Unreachable code detected
                for (int i = 0; i < no_of_cam; i++)
#pragma warning restore CS0162 // Unreachable code detected
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // obtém o dispositivo de entrada do vídeo
                        Camera = CamContainer.VideoInputDevices[i];

                        // inicializa a Captura usando o dispositivo
                        CaptureInfo = new DirectX.Capture.Capture(Camera, null);

                        // Define a janela de visualização do vídeo
                        CaptureInfo.PreviewWindow = this.picWebCam;

                        // Capturando o tratamento de evento
                        CaptureInfo.FrameCaptureComplete += AtualizaImagem;

                        // Captura o frame do dispositivo
                        CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();

                        // Se o dispositivo foi encontrado e inicializado então sai sem checar o resto
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                {
                    this.TopMost = false;
                    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void AtualizaImagem(PictureBox frame)
        {
            try
            {
                CapturaImagem = frame.Image;
                this.picImagem.Image = CapturaImagem;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnCaptura_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta
                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
                {
                    Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
                    Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
                    InitialDirectory = @"\\MI7627\Imagens"
                };
                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

                // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
                if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
                {
                    // salva a imagem por fileStream
                    System.IO.FileStream fs =
                       (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
                    // Salva a imagem no formato certo
                    switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                            break;
                    }

                    fs.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void picWebCam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde você está setando o tamanho desejado? Obs.: algumas câmeras limitam a resolução ao operar no modo webcam.

Comment: então cara esse é o problema, ja pesquisei diversos códigos e tentei de diversas maneiras, não consigo setar uma resolução, na realidade nem preciso trocar a resolução, apenas setar uma maior que 600x400

Comment: Veja as especificações da câmera que você está usando.

Answer (score -1):

Olá

Sei que passou muito tempo desde este post, mas eu consigo alterar a resolução da seguinte forma;

```
captureInfo.FrameSize = new Size(320, 240);
```

Coloque após;

```
CaptureInfo = new DirectX.Capture.Capture(Camera, null);
```

Abraços